# Too many Selenium web driver instances when using with Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, web-crawler

I am creating a web crawler using Scrapy and Selenium.

The code looks like this:

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  urls = [/* a very long list of url */] 

  def start_requests(self):
    for url in urls:
      yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_item)

  def parse_item(self, response):
     item = Item()
     item['field1'] = response.xpath('some xpath').extract()[0]
     yield item

     sub_item_url = response.xpath('some another xpath').extract()[0]

     # Sub items are Javascript generated so it needs a web driver
     options = Options()
     options.add_argument('--headless')
     options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

     driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
     driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

     sub_item_generator = self.get_sub_item_generator(driver, sub_item_url)
     while True:
        try:
            yield next(sub_item_generator)
        except StopIteration:
            break

     driver.close()

  def get_sub_item_generator(driver, url):
     # Crawling using the web driver goes here which takes a long time to finish
     yield sub_item
```

The problem is that the crawler running for a while then it crashed due to run out of memory. Scrapy keeps scheduling a new URL from the list so there are too many web driver processes running.

Is there any way to control the Scrapy scheduler not to schedule a new URL when there is some number of web driver process running?

Comment: consider using splash, more lightweight than Selenium

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) to something lower than the default of `16` [(as shown here)](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider):

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # urls = [/* a very long list of url */]
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 5  # default of 16 seemed like it was too much?
    }
```

Comment: This is not working despite setting 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' to 1. More Chrome processes were getting created until used up all memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()`

Comment: Tried and also not working. As too many Chrome processes were created and crashed due to out of memory before this line was reached.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem despite of using `driver.close()` then I did this, kill all firefox instances before the script starts.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["killall", "firefox"])
```